# Xcode: Which elements of my Xcode storyboard are causing the large file size?

Tags: ios, xcode, github

I have been working on a project for about 1.5 years now. I have been periodically making changes and adding to the project. This has included adding new View Controllers and element to the Main.storyboard.

The last time I made a normal change to the project, I am suddenly getting an error when I try to push to GitHub:

```
Main.storyboard is 433.87 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I don't understand what could have caused the size to jump so drastically.

So I have some questions:

- Is there a way to see which elements of the storyboard are causing the large file size?
- Did GitHub recently change how big a file can be?
- Is there a non-evasive way to push this file to GitHub?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Edit:

I looked at the raw text file for the storyboard and I found a very strange field.  The entire file is 5,607,859 lines long. The field below goes clear from line 15,510 to 5,607,777 (or about 99.7% of the file). Can anyone tell me why this field might exist? Or what to do about it?

[image]
...
...
...
[image]

Comment: storyboard is basically a xml file, so it shouldn't be that big. how many view controllers do you have in the storyboard file?

Comment: @Ryan I have 25 view controllers.

Comment: @Ryan You got me thinking I should take a look at the text inside the storyboard. I will edit my original post to show what I found.

Comment: Open the storyboard in Xcode. From the menu bar, choose Find > Find… (default shortcut: ⌘F). Type `5nj-m7-ZX2` in the text field and press return. If that highlights an item in the storyboard, then you have found the responsible item.

Comment: @robmayoff That did the trick. That reduced the size to 2MB. I wonder what corrupted that element?

Comment: I'd have to see more of the storyboard to figure that out.

Comment: @robmayoff Well, since I've never noticed this happening before, I think I won't spend any additional time on it. But thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ryan thanks for your help!

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer Thank you for asking this question last year !  I've come across the same problem where my storyboard picked up an item that bulked up the file.  It turned out to be an image view.  I'm wondering if you ever found out why this happened?

Comment: @JustinNgan I never figured out why it happened, and sometimes the element gets very large again after I've fixed it. Whenever this happens, I open the story board as a raw text file, find which element is the problem, go into the storyboard in Xcode, delete the element, and replace it with the same type of element (not very convenient).

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer Thanks Ryan. Yes Agee’s that it’s inconvenient. I’m pretty sure it’s something I’ve done.  It doesn’t seem to be a widespread problem. Good luck and thanks again for asking the question or I’d be hitting my head against the wall.